# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Bueno amigos, mi proyecto me lanza este error ahora, soy bastante nuevo con Laravel la verdad y pues no entiendo muy bien por los momentos, pero lo importante es aprender entre todos. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Me lanza esto directamente.

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_laravel\resources\views\layout\admin.blade.php)

Mis codigos son los siguientes

**MovieController**

```
<?php

namespace cinema\Http\Controllers;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use cinema\Http\Requests;
use cinema\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use cinema\Genre;
use cinema\Movie;

class MovieController extends Controller{

public function index(){
    //
}



public function create(){
    $genres = Genre::lists('genre','id');
    return view('pelicula.create',compact('genres'));
}

public function store(Request $request){
    Movie::create($request->all());
    return "Listo";
}
```

**admin.blade.php** <-- Según aquí esta el error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Panel Administración</title>

    {!!Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
    {!!Html::style('css/metisMenu.min.css')!!}
    {!!Html::style('css/sb-admin-2.css')!!}
    {!!Html::style('css/font-awesome.min.css')!!}

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Cinema Admin</a>
        </div>


        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
             <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    {!!Auth::user()->name!!}<i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Ajustes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    @if(Auth::user()->tipoUser == 'Administrador')
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Usuario<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                     <a href="/usuario/create"><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Agregar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                <a href="/usuario"><i class='fa fa-list-ol fa-fw'></i> Usuarios</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/ususariosEliminados"><i class='fa fa-list-ol fa-fw'></i> Usuarios Eliminados</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        @endif
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film fa-fw"></i> Pelicula<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/pelicula/create"><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Agregar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class='fa fa-list-ol fa-fw'></i> Peliculas</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child fa-fw"></i> Genero<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/genero/create"><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Agregar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/genero"><i class='fa fa-list-ol fa-fw'></i> Generos</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

     </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

    </div>



    {!!Html::script('js/jquery.min.js')!!}
    {!!Html::script('js/bootstrap.min.js')!!}
    {!!Html::script('js/metisMenu.min.js')!!}
    {!!Html::script('js/sb-admin-2.js')!!}

    @section('script')

    @show

</body>

</html>
```

**Create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.admin')

@section('content')
@include('alertas.ErroresFormulario')

{!!Form::open(['route'=>'pelicula.store', 'method'=>'POST','files'=>  true])!!}
    @include('pelicula.forms.crearPelicula')
    {!!Form::submit(['Registrar','class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}

@endsection
```

Y el ultimo codigo **crearPelicula**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('nombre','Nombre:')!!}
    {!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese Nombre de la pelicula'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('elenco','Elenco:')!!}
    {!!Form::text('cast',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese el elenco'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('direccion','Dirección:')!!}
    {!!Form::text('direction',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese el Director'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('duracion','Duración:')!!}
    {!!Form::text('duration',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Duración de la pelicula'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('Poster','Poster:')!!}
    {!!Form::file('path')!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('Genero','Genero:')!!}
    {!!Form::select('genre_id',$generos)!!}
</div>
```

**Disculpen por lo largo del codigo, pero espero me puedan ayudar, muchisimas gracias**.

Comment: Sería bueno saber que línea referencia el error, al parecer el usuario autenticado no tiene la propiedad `name` o `tipoUser`.

Comment: No me referecia ninguna linea, me manda el error así en seco directamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira bien las variables que utilizas:

```
public function create(){
    $genres = Genre::lists('genre','id');
    return view('pelicula.create',compact('genres'));
}

{!!Form::select('genre_id',$generos)!!}
```

Mandas **$genres** e intentas utilizar **$generos**

Soluciona eso y mira si te sigue saliendo el error, en tal caso puede ser que tus usuarios no tenga la propiedad `tipoUser`.

Comment: Creeme que muchas veces me percate de eso, y ahora lo hice y si me dio. **Muchas gracias**